# Как ограничить длину выводимых значений при SELECT?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица `propose`, поле `image` это большой байтовый массив и при выборке `select * from propose where id = '?';` в терминале получается ужасный бардак. Можно ли сделать так что бы выводилось не все значение поля `image` а первые 5 символов?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS propose (
     id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
     id_auhtor INTEGER NOT NULL ,
     sold BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
     description TEXT NOT NULL ,
     mark TEXT NOT NULL ,
     model TEXT NOT NULL ,
     image BYTEA,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (id_auhtor) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию `substring`:

```
select substring(bytea_contents from offset for length) FROM table;
```

Для вашего примера:

```
select id,id_auhtor,sold,description,mark,model,substring(image from 0 for 5) AS cuted_img from propose where id = '?';
```